# California: what happens if HVAC fails HERS?

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, ducts, california

In California, I recently had my AC and furnace replaced and am getting a [Home Energy Rating System (HERS) test](https://www.energy.ca.gov/programs-and-topics/programs/home-energy-rating-system-hers-program) done as part of the permit paperwork.

The contractor did not make modifications to my ducts other than patching leaks in the return ducting and connecting it to the new system.

What happens if my ducts fail HERS? I've tried reading the relevant Title 24 code; the code seems to say the builder is responsible for fixing the issue, but the passages seem to be primarily addressing construction of new tract housing. It's not clear to me what would happen in this situation.

Comment: From https://www.energy.ca.gov/programs-and-topics/programs/home-energy-rating-system-hers-program - "The HERS Program, also called the Field Verification and Diagnostic Testing Program, is a way to ensure that the various features of a home meet the California Building Energy Efficiency Standards (Energy Code). If work requires HERS testing, a rater will perform field verification and diagnostic testing on the appropriate features. If the system fails, the contractor is required to fix it."

Comment: @JonCuster I saw that, but that description seems like a simplified summary rather than anything legally binding. I'm not sure if it still applies if the contractor didn't work on the ducts.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it.

Comment: i would contact your local building inspector

Comment: "What happens if the ducts fail"? "Is the builder responsible"? This comes down to opinion until it fails then the builder does or does not correct it.

Comment: @SolarMike It's a question about building code, which in theory is not subject to opinion. Arguably the question is better suited for the Law SE but since it's about code I figured I'd post here.

Comment: If it fails code then take the builder to court - guaranteed outcome? good luck.